# Can I put several macros in one?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a sheet where I have rows that get a timestamp in the column next to it, if the content in the cell changes.

What do I do wrong in the following macro? The first macro works on its own, but not if I add several macros.

---

```
Sub Update01()

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    With Target.Offset(0, 1)    
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"    
    End With
End Sub


Sub Update02()
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 3 Then Exit Sub

    With Target.Offset(0, 3)    
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM" 
    End With    
End


Sub Main()
    Call Update01
    Call Update02
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) You can't nest subs (2) The `WorksheetChange` event runs when a cell is changed, and is not called from another sub (3) You can't adjust its name or parameter.

Comment: (4) In `Update02` the variabe `Target` is not declared and does not exist. • This looks like a [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you ask about X but your actual problem is Y. Try to explain what you are actually trying to do and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do something like the following

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1)    
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"    
        End With
    ElseIf Target.Column = 3
        With Target.Offset(0, 3)    
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM" 
        End With    
    End If
ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that you need to `Application.EnableEvents = False` before writing a value to a cell otherwise this would trigger the `Worksheet_Change` over and over again.

Also note that `Worksheet_Change` is an event. That means it runs automatically whenever a cell value in the worksheet gets changed. You cannot run this procedure manually and you cannot `Call` it.